# In neo4j, how do I create a new record if it does not exist, but update attributes if it does?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My data is as follows:

```
Name | Age | Status
-----|-----|--------
Bill |  23 | Married
John |  19 | Single
```

Now, I want to search the records by name "Jim". If the record is found, I would like to set the age to 30 and status to single. If not, I want to create a new record with the name as "Jim" with age 30 and status single.

I managed to do this with the merge command like so:

```
MERGE (n:person {name:"Jim"}) 
on match set age=30, status="Single"
on create set age=30, status="Single"
```

But this seems inefficient to me since I am repeating the same statements on match and on create. Is there a better way to do this?

(The way I formed the question may be confusing. I apologise for it.)

Comment: As you are not really updating the `status` property `on match` as it is already "Single"; you can remove that part otherwise rest of it looks fine to me. This is the way to do it. Refer the [Cypher Refcard](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/).

Comment: Your approach is proper @sudhanva. Because in MERGE clause only one of match or create will execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are doing the same `on match` and `on create` I think you can simply remove it and do a `SET` in both properties after `MERGE`. This way will works:

```
MERGE (n:person {name:"Jim"}) 
SET n.age=30, n.status="Single"
```